# Creating subset of the dict elements having {key:list[]}

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have a dict with list elements for each key. eg.

```
config_dict = {"num":[2,3,4],
               "dist":[10,30,22],
               "type":["free"],
               "uphill":[1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-6]
               }
```

I want to create a function which creates all possible subset of elements for each key as a new dict. eg

```
new_config = {'congfig_1': { "num":2,
                             "dist":22,
                             "type":"free",
                             "uphill":1e-3
                           }
              'config_2': { "num":3,
                             "dist":22,
                             "type":"free",
                             "uphill":1e-6
                           }
              'config_3': { "num":2,
                             "dist":10,
                             "type":"free",
                             "uphill":1e-3
                           }
               ...
              }
```

I am stuck on the implementation as each key might have a different length of lists. Is there an elegant way to do this/ pythonic way without many loops ?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have the output as a list of dicts instead?

Comment: Yeah. That works too. I typed in the way I envisioned it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

config_dict = {"num":[2,3,4],
               "dist":[10,30,22],
               "type":["free"],
               "uphill":[1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-6]
               }

output = {f'config_{i}': {'num': num, 'dist': dist, 'type': type, 'uphill': uphill}
         for i, (num, dist, type, uphill) in enumerate(product(*config_dict.values()), 1)}

print(output)
```

However, it may make more sense to create a list of dictionaries instead:

```
output = [{'num': num, 'dist': dist, 'type': type, 'uphill': uphill}
          for (num, dist, type, uphill) in product(*config_dict.values())]
```

Comment: is there a way to omit explicitly writing the keys ? I did get this working. But everytime I add a new key to the dict, i have to explicitly write that here too

Comment: I think we can do it. I have added a answer. Tag it in your ans for future ref.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of @DeepSpace
We can prevent the explicit typing of the keys in creation of this new dict by

```
config_keys = config_dict.keys()
for i, values in product(*config_dict.values()):
   output[f'config_{i}'] = dict(zip(config_keys, values))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write with no libraries

```
def combinatrix(dictLeft):
    sol=list()
    key=list(dictLeft.keys())[0]
    temp2=dict(dictLeft)
    del temp2[key]
    if(len(temp2)==0):
        for item in dictLeft.get(key):
            temp=dict()
            temp[key]=item
            sol.append(temp)
    else:
        a=combinatrix(temp2)
        for item in dictLeft.get(key):
            for b in a:
                b=dict(b)
                b[key]=item
                sol.append(b)
    return sol

config_dict = {"num":[2,3,4],
               "dist":[10,30,22],
               "type":["free"],
               "uphill":[1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-6]
               }

sol=combinatrix(config_dict)
print(sol)
```